# Questions on Inheritance and Overriding

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I currently have a piece of software that uses two classes that are identical in every every way, they have the same 25 or so data members and have one function that does the calculations to fill those data members.  How the two differ is in the calculation function.  Each class performs a different calculation to fill those 25 private data members.

So what I did was create a base class that has the 25 data members and created all the getter / setter methods here, then, created two new classes that inherited this base class and just created a calculation function for each of these new classes that inherit the base.  The function that does the calculating has the same name between both of the child classes, but does something different in each one.  My question is, Is there a way I can include that calculate function in the base class that they inherit and just define them different in each sub class?  I'm still pretty new to overriding, but would this be a place to do it? If so, how could I go about doing that?  I realize that it's not a huge deal, I'm only barely repeating myself, but I'd like to keep things as DRY as possible.

Comment: You override a base class virtual function in subsequent derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a pure virtual function in your base class.  Something like this:

```
struct base {
  int field;
  virtual void set_field(int) = 0;
};

struct typeA : base {
  void set_field(int val) override { field = /* some function of */ val; }
};

struct typeB : base {
  void set_field(int val) override { field = /* some function of */ val; }
};
```

The `= 0` in the base class declares `set_field` as a *pure virtual function*, meaning a function that doesn't have an implementation in the `base`.  Because `base` has one or more pure virtual functions, it is a *pure virtual class*--you can never create objects of type `base`, only subtypes.

What inheritance gives you, however, is that you can operate on a pointer or reference to a base class (even a pure virtual class) without needing to know what the derived type is.  That means You can write a function `void f(base &)` that calls `set_field`, and you can call `f` on objects of `typeA` or `typeB`.

Comment: Great! I think it all makes sense, except a couple things.  Would you be willing to elaborate on why the pure virtual needs a =0; at the end? It's a little confusing, does it just mean that the function is literally missing since it's just a virtual?  Also, the comment about using a base *, would you be able to expand how that could be used instead of going through type A or B? I think I'm just mixing something up there.

Comment: @joe_04_04 I clarified this in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It all makes sense now! :)

Comment: So, since my base class has setter / getters defined, it cannot be a pure virtual class?  I tried making the `calculate` function a pure virtual function, but then the compiler complained about the class not having a pure virtual destructor, after I gave it a pure virtual instructor, it then complained that the base class wasn't pure virtual, but then I realized I had defined setter / getter methods, so I assume I cannot add a pure virtual function to it?